# Grouping in cells with VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I wnat to do some grouping in excel using VBA

My "criteria" column is "A" which is general a list of number that are obviously redundant and should be grouped to give the user a better understanding of the excel sheet

I have named column "A" "Vertrag__Nr."

My Code

```
Sub Test()
Dim i As Integer, LastRow As Integer

LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To LastRow

    If Not Left(Cells(i, 1), 2) = "Vertrag__Nr." Then
        Cells(i, 2).EntireRow.Group
    End If

Next i
End Sub
```

My problem is that my code instead of grouping by entries "Vertrag _Nr." (Column A) In groups the whole column into one big groupe

[image]

Comment: From what I can see, your code would do a one big group. Can you provide a snapshot of your worksheet?

Comment: @zac i have updated my question

Comment: So, in example you provided, what rows should be grouped?

Comment: @MichałTurczyn All of them according to column A

Comment: But how can you group them all in one group if they all are different? It doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @MichałTurczyn they are all different as said above in column  for example there are multiple entereies with the value 1 and i want to group them that all values that are 1 are in one gorupe (Column A)

Comment: `Left(Cells(i, 1), 2) = "Vertrag__Nr."` will always be `False` because `"Vertrag__Nr."` has 12 characters....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as grouping is used for summaries, there has to be a place for summary between groups, they cannot be contiguous, try this code:

```
Sub Test()
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, LastRow As Integer
Dim currVal As Variant
    With ActiveSheet
        LastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        i = 2

        While i <= LastRow
            currVal = .Cells(i, 1).Value
            j = 0
            Do
                j = j + 1
            Loop Until .Cells(i + j, 1).Value <> currVal
            If j > 1 Then
                .Rows(i + j).Insert
                .Cells(i + j, 1).Value = currVal
                Range(.Cells(i, 1), .Cells(i + j - 1, 1)).EntireRow.Group
            End If
            i = i + j
        Wend
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: thats nice thank you so much for your time and effort ! :)$